# Tab not working in mozilla

Tags: forms, laravel, google-chrome, mozilla

I have stucked with small issue. If anyone knows solution please kindly help me

[image]

from amount if I press tab it is moving to quantity tab in chrome. But in mozilla its not tabbing why is this so?

If anyone knows please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

you can control your tab by tabindex
set it input as

```
tabindex=1
```

so on as your req. 
hope this will help you!